# Page loading timeout, refreshing - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a link on my codeigniter live project :

```
<a href="https://businessactioncomplete.com/action_station/crmmails/viewmails?page=1" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Check Incoming Emails</a>
```

When i click this link, it starts loading the page, it calls the viewmails() function in crmmails.php , the script runs for a few minutes, exactly after two minutes, function execution stops, the viewmails() function runs again from start. I know this from my debug files :

```
crmmails running viewmails function 2019-03-01 03:34:06am // first call
crmmails before emails_view 2019-03-01 03:34:06am
crmmails running viewmails function 2019-03-01 03:36:06am // second call
crmmails before emails_view 2019-03-01 03:36:06am
crmmails after emails_view 2019-03-01 03:36:07am
```

Why is it happening? Where do i need to check for such a setting. I want to stop it from refreshing because my script has to run for a longer time.

Answer (score 0):

Modify maximum execution time in `php.ini`

```
; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 120
```

Comment: i changed it from 30 to 240 but the problem is still the same i.e. 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

I checked your URL, it is opening. But some errors exist in your code.

You should change your execution time in php.ini file

Comment: you might have got error 79 which occurs when you are not logged in.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/Crmmails.php

Line Number: 81

Backtrace:

File: /home4/ceobusac/public_html/action_station/application/controllers/Crmmails.php
Line: 81
Function: _error_handler

File: /home4/ceobusac/public_html/action_station/index.php
Line: 321
Function: require_once

Comment: it is ok, it throws errors if one is not a logged in user.